# Variables not displaying in rails blog post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a simple blog tool using rails and having trouble with variables displaying from a form. What is most confusing is that the post times are showing correctly, but the title and text aren't coming through.

My new form page looks like:

```
<h1>New post</h1>

<%= form_for :blog, url: blogs_path do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

The controller is currently:

```
class BlogsController < ApplicationController
def index
end

def new
end

def create
    @blog = Blog.new(post_params[:id])
    @blog.save

    redirect_to @blog
end

def show
    @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
end

private
    def post_params
        params.require(:blog).permit(:title, :body)
    end
end
```

And the show page is:

```
<div id="blog">
    <h1>
        <%= @blog.title %>
    </h1>

    <p class="date">
        Submitted <%= time_ago_in_words(@blog.created_at) %> ago
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= @blog.body %>
    </p>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `Blog.new(post_params[:id])` looks suspicious. From what I've checked, that should crash with an `ArgumentError`.

Comment: Indeed, there are some cases where you want to save only the id however here it doesn't make sense you should just pass `post_params` to the new instance of Blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
def create
    @blog = Blog.new(post_params[:id])
    @blog.save

    redirect_to @blog
end
```

to:

```
def create
    @blog = Blog.new(post_params)
    @blog.save

    redirect_to @blog
end
```

The reason why it wasn't working is that you were only trying to save`post_params[:id]`. You need to pass the whole param as an argument when creating a new blog post `Blog.new(post_params)`

Comment: Yup, that did it! So, if I understand correctly, when you save post_params, if you specify certain ones you only save those?

Comment: That's correct :). If that solved your problem please check my answer as the accepted one.